# How does $x\log_2 y - \log_2 y = x +1$ become $\log_2 y = \frac{{x+1} }{x-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently doing a pre-calculus course and I stumbled upon this.
I know this is basic algebra, but I can't find the rule used to go from:
$$x\log_2(y) - \log_2(y) = x +1$$
to:
$$\log_2(y) = \frac{{x+1} }{x-1}$$

> Where does the $x - 1$ come from? What are the mathematical rules used here? What rule(s) allow us to get rid of one  $\log_2(y)$ term?

Thank you

Comment: $x\log_2(y) - \log_2(y) = (x-1)\log_2(y)$

Comment: "What rule(s) allow us to get rid of one log2(y) term".  The same rule that always one to turn $5M - M$ to $4M$ and allows us to "get rid of" one $M$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\log_2(y) - \log_2(y) = x +1$

$\color{red}x\color{green}{\log_2(y)} - \color{red}1\cdot \color{green}{\log_2(y)} = x +1$

$\color{green}{\log_2(y)}( \color{red}x -\color{red}1) = x+1$ so if we assume $x \ne 1$ then

$\color{green}{\log_2(y)} = \frac {x+1}{( \color{red}x -\color{red}1)}$

....  alternatively....

Let $\log_2(y) = M$.

THen $xM - M = x+1$

$M(x-1)= x+1$ and if $x \ne 1$ then

$M = \frac{x+1}{x-1}$.

$\log_2 y = \frac {x+1}{x-1}$

..... Thing is, you are just distributing like you have done many times in the past.  The fact that you are dealing with logarithms doesn't really matter at this step of the solution.

=====

> What rule(s) allow us to get rid of one log2(y) term?

None.

We don't get rid of it.

We combine the two terms, $x\log_2 y$ and $-\log_y$ , to get a single term, (but one that is different from the other two), of $(x-1)\log_2 y$.

.........

And just to be perverse and *NASTY*....

$x\log_2 (y) - \log_2 (y) = x+1$

$\log_2 (y^x) - \log_2 (y) = x+1$

$\log_2 (\frac {y^x}y) = x+1$

$\log_2 (y^{x-1}) = x+1$

$2^{x+1} = y^{x-1}$

$(2^{x+1})^{\frac 1{x-1}} = y$ (assuming $x\ne 1$)

$2^{\frac {x+1}{x-1}} = y$ so

$\log_2 y = \frac {x+1}{x-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Distributivity: $x\log_2(y)-\log_2(y)=x\times\log_2(y)-1\times\log_2(y)=(x-1)\log_2(y).$